# How to convert timestamp with time zone to local time format with pandas?

Tags: pandas, time

Let's say I have a column called timestamp with values from the following format -
`2023-02-04 08:08:42+03:00` (when the dtype is `Timestamp`)

The expected result of the conversion should be `2023-02-04 05:08:42`

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
import pandas as pd
s=pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('now', 
tz='America/Chicago')])
t=s.dt.tz_convert('utc').dt.tz_localize(None)
print(s,t)
```